# How create a shadow of three sides in UIView (Right, Left, Bottom) in swift 4?

Tags: uiview, swift4, shadow

I am tried to create a shadow of UIView(Right, left, bottom), does not create an exact shadow. How can I create a shadow of UIView(like below image)? Please help me!

[Shadow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjH9Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add drop shadow to your view using `UIBezierPath` like this:

```
extension UIVIew{
     func applyDropShadow(scale: Bool = true) {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
        layer.shadowRadius = 1

        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
      }
}
```

adjust the `shadowOffset` to get the design shadow position.